# Get active file of frontmost application in OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsworkspace, accessibility-api

Is there any chance to get the active file of a frontmost application (given that the app has opened a file) in Objective-C via NSWorkspace, Accessibility API, Applescript or the like?